# cannot find symbol Serializable?

Tags: java, serialization, compiler-errors, serializable

Why does this:

```
package com.example;

import com.example.Foo.Bar.Baz;

import java.io.Serializable; // I did import Serializable...

public class Foo implements Serializable {

    public final Bar bar;

    public Foo(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar == null ? new Bar(Baz.ONE) : bar;
    }

    public static class Bar implements Serializable { // this is line 15, where the compiler error is pointing 

        public enum Baz {
            ONE
        }

        public final Baz baz;

        public Bar(Baz baz) {
            this.baz = baz;
        }
    }

}
```

Give me this:

```
[ERROR] <path to file>/Foo.java:[15,44] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Serializable
[ERROR] location: class com.example.Foo
```

If I replace the Serializable interface to something else like :

```
public interface MyMarkerInterface {}
```

then the code compiles. (even `Cloneable` works!)

What makes this happen?
intelliJ didn't spot anything wrong through static analysis.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't try and import the internal class. That's causing your compiler error

```
// import com.example.Foo.Bar.Baz;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Foo implements Serializable {
    public final Bar bar;

    public Foo(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar == null ? new Bar(Bar.Baz.ONE) : bar;
    }

    public static class Bar implements Serializable {
        public enum Baz {
            ONE
        }
        public final Baz baz;
        public Bar(Baz baz) {
            this.baz = baz;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't explain why `Cloneable ` or any other interface works

Comment: Look at the order of your import(s). Can Bar be `Serializable` (and used) before you import `Serializable`? eclipse reordered them.

Comment: Oh wow, now I understand why. It was pretty hard to spot when inteliJ/Eclipse fold and hide all the imports

Answer (score 0):

in java7 and java8 compiling depended on order of imports.
your code works in java >= 9. see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8066856 and https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7101822

to make it compile in java7 and java8 just reorder the imports